# Dequeues linked lists

Tags: c++, deque

This is the output of my program :

```
Initial Queue
40 30

40 was popped from back
30

New Queue
12 10 8 30
```

I am having problem with the function push_back, I am tring `push 12 10 8 after 30`, in other words the output should be `30 8 10 12`

Any suggestions

```
#include <cstddef> 
class ListNode {
public:
ListNode() {next=NULL;};
int get_data() {return data;};
ListNode * get_next() {return next;};
void set_data(int data) {this->data = data;};
void set_next(ListNode *next) {this->next = next;};
private:
int data;
ListNode *next;
};

#include "dequeue.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
DeQueue q;

q.push_back(30);
q.push_back(40);
cout << "Initial Queue" << endl;
cout << q << endl;


    cout << q.pop_back() << " was popped from back" << endl;
    cout << q << endl;
q.push_back(8);
q.push_back(10);
q.push_back(12);
cout << "New Queue" << endl;
cout << q << endl;

}

 #include "dequeue.h"

DeQueue::~DeQueue()
{
delete [] storage;
}
int DeQueue::pop_back()
{

if(storage == NULL){ //queue is empty!
    return -1; //should throw exception
}
int return_data = storage->get_data();
ListNode *tmp = storage;

storage = storage->get_next();
delete tmp;
return return_data;
}



void DeQueue::push_back(int data)//front
{
ListNode *tmp = new ListNode;
tmp->set_next(storage);
tmp->set_data(data);

storage = tmp;
}


ostream & operator <<(ostream &os, DeQueue &q)
{
ListNode *tmp = q.storage;
while(tmp!=NULL){
    os << tmp->get_data() << " ";
    tmp = tmp->get_next();
}
os << endl;
return os;
 }

#include "list.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class DeQueue {
friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &os, DeQueue &q);
public:
DeQueue(){storage=NULL;};
~DeQueue();
int pop_front();
int pop_back(); 
void push_front(int data); 
void push_back(int data);
 private:
ListNode *storage;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

A double ended queue has most likely two pointers: `ListNode *front, *back;` because otherwise it is not possible to pop the back without iterating through the whole deque if you don't know  where it is. Also you should save both, the previous and the next element in your `ListNode`.

Before fixing that it is not possible to properly implement `pop_back` and `push_back`.